# How to write the gauge-invariant anomalous Nambu Green's function for 2D square lattice with uniform $\pi$ flux?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance, greens-functions

For the free fermion system in two-dimensional square lattice, we add the $\pi$ flux in each plateau:
$$H=-t \sum_{\langle i, j\rangle} e^{i A_{i, j}} c_{i}^{\dagger} c_{j}+h . c .$$
where
$$\sum_{\square} A_{i, j}=\Phi=\pi$$
and there exists gauge transform:
$$\begin{array}{l}c_{i}^{\dagger} \rightarrow c_{i}^{\dagger} e^{-i \theta_{i}} \\ c_{j} \rightarrow c_{j} e^{i \theta_{j}} \\ A_{i, j} \rightarrow A_{i, j}+\theta_{i}-\theta_{j}\end{array}$$
I can obtain the dispersion by choosing a gauge, e.g.

[image]

Now, I want to write the gauge invariant Green's function, some reference [footnote 9 in page 68](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/pdf/10.1103/RevModPhys.78.17)  says the gauge invariant Green's function in the system with gauge field can be written as:
$$G(x)=-\left\langle c(x) c^{\dagger}(0) e^{i \int_{0}^{x} A d x}\right\rangle$$
where $e^{i \int_{0}^{x} A d x}$ is the straight line which connects beginning point and end point.

I can understand that the additional term $e^{i \int_{0}^{x} A d x}$ recovers the gauge invariance of conventional Green's function.  However, I am confused that how to recovers the gauge invariance of BCS-type Nambu Green's function, i.e.  how to write the gauge invariant anomalous Green's function like: $$F(x)=-\left\langle c(x) c(0) \right\rangle$$